# Fixed date to be use for date conversion

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Is there a way I can have a fixed date that I will use for conversion.

as you can see, the code below states that it is the time in Manila, PH but when you open it given that you are in a different timezone to me it will give you different time. Date(); will just get the time in your computer.

Is there a way to get a date which will be use as a default date so that I can add or minus hours to get my desired conversion date even though it will be open in different timezones?

```js
function showTime() {
        var a_p = "";
        var today = new Date();
        var curr_hour = today.getHours();
        var curr_minute = today.getMinutes();
        var curr_second = today.getSeconds();
 var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
 var myDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
 var date = new Date();
 var day = date.getDate();
 var month = date.getMonth();
 var thisDay = date.getDay(),
     thisDay = myDays[thisDay];
 var yy = date.getYear();
 var year = (yy < 1000) ? yy + 1900 : yy;
     
        if (curr_hour < 12) {
            a_p = "<span>AM</span>";
        } else {
            a_p = "<span>PM</span>";
        }
        if (curr_hour == 0) {
            curr_hour = 12;
        }
        if (curr_hour > 12) {
            curr_hour = curr_hour - 12;
        }
        curr_hour = checkTime(curr_hour);
        curr_minute = checkTime(curr_minute);
        curr_second = checkTime(curr_second);
      document.getElementById('clock-large1').innerHTML=curr_hour + " : " + curr_minute + " : " + curr_second + " " + a_p;
 document.getElementById('date-large1').innerHTML="<b>" + thisDay + "</b>, " + day + " " + months[month] + " " + year;
        }

    function checkTime(i) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = "0" + i;
        }
        return i;

    }
    setInterval(showTime, 500);
```

```html
<div id="clockdate-full">
  <div class="wrapper-clockdate1">
    <div id="clock-large1"></div>
    <div id="date-large1"></div>
    <div id="timezone">Manila, PH</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you can use Date.UTC(), my friend. Visit this link to refer more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a date which will be use as a default date so that I can add or minus hours to get my desired conversion date even though it will be open in different timezones?

Yes, just specify the "fixed" date in a suitable format. Most browsers will parse ISO 8601 extended format strings like 2017-05-25T17:35:48+08:00. That represents 5:30pm in Manilla, which is UTC+08:00.

To get the equivalent time on the user's system:

```js
var d = new Date('2017-05-25T17:35:48+08:00');

console.log(d.toString()); // equivalent local time
```

If you want to support browsers like IE 8, you'll need to parse the string manually or use a library with a parser, e.g. [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) or [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout moment .js

http://momentjs.com

You can specify the time zone of the date time

```
var timezone = 'America/Chicago'
moment().tz(timezone).format('hh:mm:ss z')
```

If you can't use an external link, you should try the code below:

```
var opt= {
    timeZone: 'America/Chicago',
    year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'
},
    formatDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], opt)
formatDate.format(new Date())
```

Comment: Hi Partrick, I will try this one but I am currently using web parts on the sharepoint and I think linking an external js is not possible. Is there any other way to achieve this if the sharepoint page doesn't accept the link.